# Laravel. Как создать два JS бандла или более?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

Как, используя laravel mix или иным путем создать два бандла?

На данный момент webpack создает один JS-бандл

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Это для того, чтобы подключать к разным шаблонам разный набор скриптов и таким образом, уменьшив вес JS, ускорить отображение страниц. Или есть иные решения для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел я ответ на свой вопрос.
Оказалось достаточно добавить в файл

```
mix.js('resources/js/my_script.js', 'public/js');
```